# In Centos, where is the default or global tmux configuration files stored?

Tags: centos, tmux

I haven't used tmux in awhile and I forgot where is this installed. how can I find out where this is installed and which default / global configuration file is being loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Just do 'rpm -ql tmux' to see all the files that are installed by that package.